# React native - When i lock the screen while API call loading, App process stopped

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to show a large list in react native - Expo. When I lock the screen while data loading via API. App State changed from "Active" to "Inactive".
When I return to an active state, no data has been loaded. The App processes are stopped.  ListEmptyComponent renders the ActivityIndicator. It is loading indefinitely. It occurs only in android build.

I tried to recall the API by [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate).

```
  const handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    console.log(nextAppState);   
    if (nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Store.apiCall));
      // "Store.apiCall" has data about last API Call and its status.
      if (Store.apiCall.status === codes.PENDING || Store.apiCall.status === codes.ERROR) {
        api(Store.apiCall.payload);
      }
    }
    setAppState(nextAppState);
  };
```

Still it doesn't works..

Answer (score 2):

This happening because of the battery optimization features of newer Android versions. The only fix would be to ask the user to disable the battery optimization for your app by redirecting them to your app settings or you can use a node package like this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-disable-battery-optimizations

Also, if you dont want your device to sleep if its in active state you can use something like this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keep-awake

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually i turned off the battery optimisation for my app. still i am having this problem.